# Can SQL Azure Reporting support a multi-tenancy model discretely/opaquely?

Tags: sql, azure, reporting, multi-tenant

We are storing multiple tenants in one instance of SQL Azure.  I have been doing some research, but I cannot determine if SQL Azure Reporting can support a multi-tenant model *discretely*.

For example, we want to run reports for a user based on their "tenancy", but we want their tenant ID to be completely opaque to them- not contained in a query string, or anything view-able by the user.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?  What was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you had the restriction that a User can only belong to a single tenant, you can hop from a User to the corresponding tenant without them having to know their tenant Id. So any of your Tenant related queries could automatically be filtered by the logged-in user.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mike.  Do you have suggestions how I would hop from User to Tenant in a SQL Azure Reporting scenario?  I am relatively new to this technology.

Comment: Ahhh...didn't realize you were saying for reporting services. Are you providing the user direct access to the Reporting? Or exposing the reports through a portal? Using the portal, you can add a parameter to the query for the tenantId and pass it in to the request for the report.

Comment: I think this is more than an SO question can cover. If you have time, we can work through it together. Then I can write it up and link to it from here. E-mail firstinitiallastname at kharasoft dot com

Comment: Mike- You are a gracious man for offering extra help over email.  I've been banging away at this problem, and I think I have a tentative solution.  I'll be testing it sometime today or tomorrow.  I'll respond to this thread with the results.

Comment: Did you find work out an approach to this issue? I am starting to design a solution where I would like to expose the end user access to azure SSRS but ensure they can only access information within their tenant.

Comment: Did Mike Brown or "a developer" solve the problem?  I am interested in the result if you have it.